# Swift 3 - How do I insert TableViewCells from another view?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am using Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.

I am trying to figure out how to insert cells into my table view from another tab of my tabbed view controller.

**MyTableView**

```
class MyTableView: UITableViewController {

    var items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]

    ...

    func insertCell() {
        items.append("Item \(items.count + 1)")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

If I create a bar button item on that table view page, I can successfully insert items, no problem.  It's when I try to trigger it from another view controller that nothing happens.

**Another Tab**

```
@IBAction func triggerInsert(_ sender: Any) {
    //MyTableView().insertCell()  // this doesn't work

    //MyTableView().items.append("Item")  // these two lines don't work either
    //MyTableView().tableView.reloadData()

    // also tried setting a boolean in here to be read from MyTableView but that didn't work either
}
```

I'm not quite sure what the "correct" way to do this is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this expression you keep trying to use:

```
MyTableView()
```

That *creates* a completely new and separate table view controller. But that obviously is not what you want to do. You want to talk to the *existing* table view controller, the one that is, as you say, another tab in the tab bar controller.

For example, if MyTableView is the *first* tab and OtherViewController is the *second* tab, then OtherViewController might say:

```
self.tabBarController!.viewControllers![0] as! MyTableView
```

...as a way of *getting a reference* to the existing table view controller.

Comment: This is what I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I hope you also understand the general lesson here.