# Swift TableView Keeps Returning Nil

Tags: swift, uitableview, viewcontroller

I have two view controllers. I am trying to call `tableview.reloadData` from the second view controller to reload my `tableview` on my first view controller but I keep getting a nil error. I am doing the following to call the table reload:

```
let VC = NotificationViewController()

VC.tableView.reloadData()
```

And I have my `tableView` defined in my first VC as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new controller and immediately trying to reload its table view long before you even present the view controller? Why are you even directly accessing the new view controller's table view?

Comment: The reloadData is being called on a button click on my second VC. The tableview is on my first VC. I am presenting my second VC to enable the user to filter results. So after they make their selection on the second VC, I want it to reload the data on the first VC.

Comment: Then you need to post more relevant code, not just two lines. Show context.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948446/swift-3-how-do-i-insert-tableviewcells-from-another-view and many others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. I first created a function to reload the table:

```
func reload() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Then used the following:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(NotificationViewController.reload),  name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadTable"), object: nil)
```

Then in the second view controller I call it with:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadTable"),  object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have two view controllers

But `NotificationViewController()` is neither of them.  It is a third, useless view controller.

Also, `VC2` and `VC` are different so your code makes no sense.

Comment: NotificationVIewController is my first view controller so no, it is not useless. Your comment is very useless as it provides no constructive feedback.

Comment: No, it is not your first view controller. It is an instance of the same class as your first view controller, but it is the wrong instance. It is a new, disconnected instance, with no interface and no table view - as you yourself have shown.  My comment is spot on. Listen and think and learn.