# Calling reload Sections from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app to track BLE devices, and I have a delegate (in appDelegate) that updates the list of discovered devices over the bluetooth.

I need to display this devices in a tableview, so when I discover a device I call a function in viewcontroller that refreshes the tableView.

If I call this function from ViewController it works, but when I call it from AppDelegate it doesn't do anything, not even an error.

AppDelegate:

```
//MARK: Discovered Device
func DeviceDiscovered(_ macAddress: String!, withName name: String!, ofType type: Int, andSignalStrength strength: Int) {
        discoveredList["\(entry["time"]!)"] = entry
        ViewController().refresh()
    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
func refresh() {
    self.tableView?.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: _sectionIndices.discoveredDevices.hashValue) as IndexSet, with: .none)
}
```

I added a button in ViewController that simply calls refresh() and it works. Or at least it reloads the section, but the discoveredList dict doesn't update in ViewController either, but one problem at a time!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating a new controller instance every time you need to refresh?

Comment: no sorry, that was just something I was trying, I use self to access the tableview, but I suspected the problem could be there... I edited the question there...

Comment: You should post a `Notification` that your view controller subscribes to in order to know that the peripheral list has been updated

Comment: @Paulw11 He _could_ do it that way, but in my opinion "should" is a bit strong.

Comment: Likely duplicate of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948446/swift-3-how-do-i-insert-tableviewcells-from-another-view - this mistake of saying `SomeClass()` without realizing that it doesn't refer to the correct instance is extremely common and has been discussed a lot on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeah, that's working ok, if I print messages to the console I can see that the update fires, and it actually enters the refresh(), but the program does not enter the cellForRowAt method.

Comment: @matt. You are right, but it was just a quick comment while I was having my morning coffee :)

Comment: I think @matt is right. However, I don't know how can I refer to the existing instance of the ViewController. As we are talking about ViewController and AppDelegate that come with a sigle view template, without a TabBar... How can I keep a fixed reference?

Comment: maybe with a singleton of the viewController??

Comment: You *could* look at using `Notification` and I *would*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ViewController()` is not your view controller. It is a new separate instance. You need to *refer* to your *existing* view controller.

Comment: do you refer to the call in AppDelegate? how can I refer to the existing one?

Comment: Only you know that. I don't know because you have not revealed where the view controller is in the view controller hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

So, as @matt pointed out, the problem was that I was instantiating a new ViewController in AppDelegate, so to solve this I did:

```
let navController       = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

newViewController       = navController.visibleViewController as! ViewController
```

to, as I understand it, pull the reference to the existing ViewController from the navigation controller.

Then refering to

```
newViewController.refresh()
```

correctly updates the tableView.

I welcome any corrections to improve this, but for now my code is working! thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: "I welcome any corrections to improve this" No, what you did is precisely what one should do!